# zf2 form collection binding

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Please, explain me how i can bind values to such a form:

```
<?php

namespace ZfcAdmin\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\Element;

class FeelistUploadForm extends Form {
        public function __construct($objectManager) {

                parent::__construct('feelist');

                $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
                $this->setAttribute('class', 'form');

                $fieldset = new FeelistFieldset($objectManager);
                $fieldset->setUseAsBaseFieldset(true);
                $this->add(array(
                        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
                        'name' => 'feelist',
                        'options' => array(
                                'label' => 'fee list',
                                'should_create_template' => true,
                                'allow_add' => true,
                                'target_element' => $fieldset,
                        ),
                ));


                $this->add(array(
                        'name' => 'submit',
                        'type' => 'Submit',
                        'attributes' => array(
                                'value' => 'Save',
                                'id' => 'submitbutton',
                                'class' => 'button',
                        ),
                ));

        }
}
```

and the fieldset

```
 class FeelistFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

        public function __construct($objectManager, $options = array()) {
               $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'InsurancyProduct\Entity\Feelist'))
                        ->setObject(new Feelist());
                parent::__construct('feelist');

                 $this->add(array(
                        'name' => 'id',
                        'type' => 'Hidden',
                 ));


                $this->add(array(
                        'name' => 'csv',
                        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\File',
                        'options' => array(
                                'label' => 'csv',
                        ),
                ));


                 $this->add(array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'name' => 'valid_from',
                        'options' => array(
                                'label' => 'valid from',
                        ),
                        'attributes'=> array(
                                'id' => 'validfrom',
                        ),
                 ));


        }

     public function getInputFilterSpecification()
     {
         return array(
         );
     }


 }
```

in the controller i use

```
$feelist_form = new \ZfcAdmin\Form\FeelistUploadForm($objectManager);
$feelist_form->bind( new feelist());
```

and i can get values for bind in controller like this

```
                $feelist = $objectManager
                        ->getRepository('InsurancyProduct\Entity\Feelist')
                        ->findBy(array('product_id' => $id));
```

i can't bind it to form, it's array of objects, but form recieves only single object.
form is of course empty and i dont know how to bind this values to form. Please, dont send me to RFTM, I have been reading it for last 48 hours, about zf2 hydration, forms, etc :(

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can take a look at this example that [rlandas wrote and uploaded to github](https://github.com/rlandas/zf2-zendformcollections)

it is a working project implementing the classic [ZendFramework2 Product-Brand-Category sample](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.collections.html)

this is the code of the controller:

```
<?php

namespace Product\Controller;

use Product\Table\ProductTable;
use Product\Entity\Product as ProductEntity;
use Product\Form\CreateProduct;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class ManageController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function indexAction ()
    {
        $product = $this->getProductTable();
        $products = $product->getAllOrderByName();

        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->setVariable('products', $products);
        return $view;
    }

    public function viewAction ()
    {
        if ($id = $this->params('id')) {
            $product = $this->getProductTable()
                ->getByProductId($id);
        }

        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->setVariable('product', $product);
        return $view;
    }

    public function addAction ()
    {
        $form = new CreateProduct();
        $product = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Product\Entity\Product');
        $form->bind($product);

        $data = array(
            'product' => array(
                'name' => 'product name ' . mt_rand(1, 1000),
                'price' => mt_rand(100.000, 5000.999) / 100,
                'brand' => array(
                    'name' => 'My brand ' . mt_rand(1, 200),
                    'url' => 'http://www.mybrand.com'
                ),
                'categories' => array(
                    array('name' => 'Sony'),
                    array('name' => 'Panasonic'),
                    array('name' => 'Phillips')
                    )
            )
        );
        $form->populateValues($data);

        // action viewscript
        $view = new ViewModel(array(
            'form' => $form
        ));

        // do Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) strategy to stop user refresh/back button
        $prg = $this->prg($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri(), true);
        if ($prg instanceof Response) {
            return $prg;
        }

        // this is when the user first arrives to this url, display the form
        else if ($prg === false) {
            return $view;
        }

        // lets retrieve the post data stored in the PRG session
        $post = $prg;

        // validate the form
        $form->setData($post);
        if(!$form->isValid())
            return $view;

        // if data are valid, then save
        // save the brand
        $brand = $product->getBrand();
        $brandTable = $this->getBrandTable();
        $brand = $brandTable->save($brand);
        $brandId = $brandTable->getLastInsertValue();
        $product->setBrandId($brandId);

        // save the categories
        $categoryTable = $this->getCategoryTable();
        $categoryTable->persist($product->getCategories())->flush();
        $categoryIds = implode(",", $categoryTable->getEntityIds());
        $product->setCategoryIds($categoryIds);

        // save the product
        $productTable = $this->getProductTable();
        $product = $productTable->save($product);

        $this->redirect()->toRoute('product');
        return $view;
    }

    public function editAction ()
    {
        $form = new CreateProduct();
        $product = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Product\Entity\Product');
        $form->bind($product);

        // action viewscript
        $view = new ViewModel(array(
            'form' => $form
        ));

        $productTable = $this->getProductTable();
        if ($id = $this->params('id')) {
            $product = $this->getProductTable()->getByProductId($id);

            // get the brands
            $brand = $this->getBrandTable()->getByBrandId($product->getBrandId());
            $product->setBrand($brand);

            // get the categories
            $categoryIds = explode(",", $product->getCategoryIds());
            $categories = $this->getCategoryTable()->getAllByCategoryId($categoryIds);
            $product->setCategories($categories);

            $form->bind($product);
        }

        // do Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) strategy to stop user refresh/back button
        $prg = $this->prg($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri(), true);
        if ($prg instanceof Response) {
            return $prg;
        }

        // this is when the user first arrives to this url, display the form
        else if ($prg === false) {
            return $view;
        }

        // lets retrieve the post data stored in the PRG session
        $post = $prg;

        // validate the form
        $form->setData($post);
        if(!$form->isValid())
            return $view;


        \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump(__METHOD__.' '.__LINE__);
        \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($post);
        \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($product);


        return $view;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \Product\Table\ProductTable
     */
    public function getProductTable ()
    {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $table = $sm->get('Product\Table\ProductTable');
        return $table;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \Product\Table\BrandTable
     */
    public function getBrandTable ()
    {
        return $this->getServiceLocator()
            ->get('Product\Table\BrandTable');
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \Product\Table\CategoryTable
     */
    public function getCategoryTable ()
    {
        return $this->getServiceLocator()
            ->get('Product\Table\CategoryTable');
    }
}
```